# Git Time Travel

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I just had an interesting git experience. I was working as the only developer on my branch `my-branch`, which I recently branched from my teammate's branch: `her-branch`. I had already successfully pushed several commits to my branch.
But when I went to push my last branch, the following happened:

```
$ git push
To git@url/repo.git
 ! [rejected]      her-branch -> her-branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@url/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejecetd because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes.
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

---

I thought it was very odd that even though I was pushing to `my-branch` the message said it failed because of `her-branch`. I didn't know what was wrong, but I pulled as the message suggested:

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

---

I wanted to confirm I was on my branch...

```
$ git checkout my-branch
Already on 'my-branch'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/my-branch'.
```

---

So finally I forced the push.

```
$ git push -f
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@url/repo.git
+ 9b3232c..d35fe86 her-branch -> her-branch (forced update)
```

---

This pushed `my-branch` successfully and updated the remote. But it sent `her-branch` back in time, with all my teammate's commits since I branched from hers removed. Her history totally disappeared from the remote.

Fortunately she didn't pull and was able to force push on her branch to recover the latest version of her code, but I'm pretty confused.

Could you please explain what happened here?

Comment: tldr: `git push` doesn't push your branch, it pushes **all** of your branches. You should not have done that, you overwrote the new version of `her-branch` with your out-of-date local version. Make sure `push.default` is set correctly.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your git config `push.default` is set to `matching`. This used to be the default behavior but as you encountered is probably not what you want for most git workflows. You can check your current setting by running `git config --get push.default`

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

> **push.default**
>
> Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is
>   explicitly given. Different values are well-suited for specific
>   workflows; for instance, in a purely central workflow (i.e. the fetch
>   source is equal to the push destination), upstream is probably what
>   you want. Possible values are:
>
> **nothing** - do not push anything (error out) unless a refspec is
>   explicitly given. This is primarily meant for people who want to avoid
>   mistakes by always being explicit.
>
> **current** - push the current branch to update a branch with the same
>   name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central
>   workflows.
>
> **upstream** - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes
>   are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called
>   @{upstream}). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the
>   same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).
>
> **simple** - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added
>   safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different
>   from the local one.
>
> When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you
>   normally pull from, work as current. This is the safest option and is
>   suited for beginners.
>
> This mode has become the default in Git 2.0.
>
> **matching** - push all branches having the same name on both ends. This
>   makes the repository you are pushing to remember the set of branches
>   that will be pushed out (e.g. if you always push maint and master
>   there and no other branches, the repository you push to will have
>   these two branches, and your local maint and master will be pushed
>   there).
>
> To use this mode effectively, you have to make sure all the branches
>   you would push out are ready to be pushed out before running git push,
>   as the whole point of this mode is to allow you to push all of the
>   branches in one go. If you usually finish work on only one branch and
>   push out the result, while other branches are unfinished, this mode is
>   not for you. Also this mode is not suitable for pushing into a shared
>   central repository, as other people may add new branches there, or
>   update the tip of existing branches outside your control.
>
> This used to be the default, but not since Git 2.0 (simple is the new
>   default).

Comment: Thanks for the info. That's helpful, but do you know what happened to cause the time travel on my coworker's branch?

Comment: @NateGardner When you ran `git push -f` you force pushed both you `my-branch` and your copy of `her-branch` overwriting the remote version of `her-branch` with your local copy. Your local copy of `her-branch` had not been updated since you branched `my-branch` off of it as `git pull` only fetched and merged the current branch (`my-branch`).

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` is just a suggestion, which cannot solve the problem in your case because her_branch is not the upstream of my_branch. It just updates my_branch with its own upstream. Instead, you should run `git pull --rebase <remote> her_branch`. `<remote>` could be `origin` or the proper remote that refers to the url of the remote repo to which her_branch belongs.

Besides, the option `-f` in `git push` is what you should always avoid when pushing to a published branch in a remote repo.

Another suggestion is always to use the full command like `git push origin HEAD:her_branch` instead of `git push`, `git pull origin her_branch` instead of `git pull`, unless you know exactly what will happen after `git push` or `git pull`.